# Strange JavaScript behavior in CodePen with humongous arrays

Tags: javascript

The following code performs a silent logical error:

```
const arr = [];
class Point{
  constructor(){
    this.x = Math.random() * 1000000;
    this.y = Math.random() * 1000000;
  }
}
console.time('foo');
let avg = 0;

for(let i = 0; i < 114000000; i++ ){
  arr.push(new Point());
  avg += arr[i].x / 1000;
}
console.log(avg, arr.length);

// shouldn't this double the avg ?
for(let i = 0; i < 114000000; i++ ){
  avg += arr[i].x / 1000;
}

console.log(avg, arr.length);
console.timeEnd('foo');
```

CodePen - http://codepen.io/darkyen/pen/yOPMZg?editors=0010

Possible behaviour(s):

- The variable `avg` after the second for loop should be doubled and The length of array should be 114 million.
- I should get a memory error.

Output when run as a script:

- `avg` Does not change after the second for loop.
- Length of the array is not 114 Mil, (Chrome 2-3M, Firefox Dev  5 Mil, MS Edge 788k).

Comment: A small note: `avg` not changing is due to the precision of floating point numbers. At some point, the value of `avg` gets so large that adding a small number to it has no effect, because of the bit size of the mantissa.

Comment: may be issue with `i<114000000` ? [codepen without any arrays](http://codepen.io/vpArth/pen/eZeGGr)

Comment: @AndersTornblad `Math.random() * 1000000 / 1000` should be in half cases more than 500, which is definitely not enough to be swallowed by rounding errors/precision for such a small number as `1261167461.290721` (for my current run)

Comment: Ah, that is true... If the array stops growing *(`.push()` fails)*, there will be no `arr[i]` to fetch the `.x` property from, which is more likely the reason for `avg` not growing. If all calls to `.push()` had succeeded, `avg` would still be off because of float errors. But I still don't know why `avg` is unchanged after the second loop.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

When you write code in Codepen - they actually don't execute it as-is but rather first apply some transformations to it.

They parse it into an [abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), find loops and [insert instructions explicitly](http://codepen.io/quezo/post/stopping-infinite-loops) to stop executing the loop if too much time has passed.

When you do:

```
for(let i = 0; i < 114000000; i++ ){
  arr.push(new Point());
  avg += arr[i].x / 1000;
}
```

Your code runs as:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 114000000; i++) {
    if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(1)) { // <- injected by Codepen!!!
        break;
    }
    arr.push(new Point());
    avg += arr[i].x / 1000;
    iter++;
}
```

You can see this by inspecting the frame code inside CodePen itself.

They inject `shouldStopLoop` calls inside your code.
They have a script called `stopExecutionOnTimeout` which does something like this (source from Codepen):

```
 var PenTimer {
   programNoLongerBeingMonitored:false,
   timeOfFirstCallToShouldStopLoop:0, // measure time
   _loopExits:{}, // keep track of leaving loops
   _loopTimers:{}, // time loops
   START_MONITORING_AFTER:2e3, // give the script some time to bootstrap
   STOP_ALL_MONITORING_TIMEOUT:5e3, // don't monitor after some time
   MAX_TIME_IN_LOOP_WO_EXIT:2200, // kill loops over 2200 ms
   exitedLoop:function(o) { // we exited a loop 
     this._loopExits[o] = false; // mark
   },
   shouldStopLoop:function(o) { // the important one, called in loops
      if(this.programKilledSoStopMonitoring)  return false; // already done
      if(this.programNoLongerBeingMonitored)return true;
      if(this._loopExits[o])  return false; 
      var t=this._getTime(); // get current time
      if(this.timeOfFirstCallToShouldStopLoop === false) 
        this.timeOfFirstCallToShouldStopLoop = t;
        return false;
      }
      var i= t - this.timeOfFirstCallToShouldStopLoop; // check time passed
      if(i<this.START_MONITORING_AFTER) return false; // still good   
      if(i>this.STOP_ALL_MONITORING_TIMEOUT){
        this.programNoLongerBeingMonitored = true;
        return false;
      }
      try{
        this._checkOnInfiniteLoop(o,t);
      } catch(n) {
        this._sendErrorMessageToEditor(); // send error about loop
        this.programKilledSoStopMonitoring=false;
        return true; // killed
      }
      return false; // no need
   },
   _sendErrorMessageToEditor:function(){/*... */
      throw "We found an infinite loop in your Pen. We've stopped the Pen from running. Please correct it or contact support@codepen.io.";
};
```

If you want to run it yourself - JSBin has similar functionality and they have [open sourced it](https://github.com/jsbin/loop-protect) as the loop-protect library - under 500 LoC.

Answer (score 11):

It's just `codepen` script runner restrictions.

I run script in `Chrome Developer Tools` and in `Node.JS REPL` - all seems ok.

---

[Codepen docs](http://codepen.io/quezo/post/stopping-infinite-loops)

Comment: Perfect! This was totally unexpected ... am removing the question as its totally misleading.

Comment: Removing question is bad option. It can be helpful for some future readers.

Comment: Actually it would be fine to add **codepen** to the title.

Comment: I started editing this answer but it ended up as being too extensive - so I've upvoted this and posted my own answer going into more details.