# Django and Java Script problems - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

Hi StackOverflow community

I am doing something wrong but can't figure out what it is. I am having trouble with some Java Script and it seems as though Django just doesn't want it. I am attempting to add the following Java Script to my site, but the code just doesn't want to stick. Here is an example that works, but I can't replicate it in the code below [code](http://codepen.io/Regaddi/pen/qZpbRj).

The javascript is supposed to take some tags such as :lol: and automatically convert it to an emoticon inside the editable p tag. It is also supposed to change :somegif: to an animated gif (please see the code via the link above for a workable example). What am I doing wrong?

Here is my HTML:

```js
(function () {
    var $input, emojiMap;
    emojiMap = {
        ':lol:': '&#x1F606;',
        ':somegif:': '<img src="http://i.giphy.com/pPzjpxJXa0pna.gif" />'
    };
    $input = $('.input');
    $input.on('keyup input', function (ev) {
        var code, range, replacement, selection, text;
        text = $input.html();
        for (code in emojiMap) {
            if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(1)) {
                break;
            }
            replacement = emojiMap[code];
            text = text.replace(code, replacement);
        }
        window.CP.exitedLoop(1);
        $input.html(text);
        range = document.createRange();
        selection = window.getSelection();
        range.setStart(this, this.childNodes.length);
        range.collapse(true);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        return selection.addRange(range);
    });
}.call(this));
```

```css
input,
.input {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: .5em;
  width: 50vh;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    {% load static from staticfiles %}
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Styles CSS -->
    <link href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- jQuery Implementation-->
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-1.12.2.min.js'%}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/rango-jquery.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
  </head>
  <body id="body_color">
    <div class="container" id="top_container">
        <div class="row"> <!-- Major Row containing both the chat window and the autoring window -->
            <div class="col-lg-4 center-block">
                <h1>{{secretDisplay.secretTitle}}</h1>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-ls-12"> 
                            <p contenteditable="true" class="center-block input"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  </body>
```

Comment: You've forgotten to tell us what the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So I figured out the answer by reviewing the answer to this question:
[Strange JavaScript behavior in CodePen with humongous arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36425678/strange-javascript-behavior-in-codepen-with-humongous-arrays/36426903#36426903)

The problem was two snippets of code, which Code Pen injects into loops.

```
if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(1)) {
            break;
}
```

And this one:

```
window.CP.exitedLoop(1);
```

Once I took these out it worked.