# CodePen running Invalid JavaScript property accessors

Tags: javascript, codepen

So, I noticed that on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/trending) invalid [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) that should give Syntax Error is working.

I have a res object:

```
let res = {
  "a" : {
    "b" : 123
  },
  "c" : 3
}
```

When I do:

```
console.log("Valid: ",  res["a"]["b"])
console.log("Invalid: ",  res.["a"].["b"])
```

I get a response on the console:

```
"Valid: " 123

"Invalid: " 123
```

As far as I know `res.["a"].["b"]` is invalid JavaScript Syntax and it doesn't work elsewhere.
Is there any reason why it's implemented this way or am I missing something?

Here's a link to my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/ahmarzaidi/pen/YzRKQXW?editors=0012) containing the code.

Comment: This seems like an issue to file with CodePen directly. [https://codepen.io/support/](https://codepen.io/support/)

Comment: Looking for documentation of CodePen's AST parsing but can't find it directly. This question touches on what is happening in the background (though it is old) [Strange JavaScript behavior in CodePen with humongous arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36425678/strange-javascript-behavior-in-codepen-with-humongous-arrays)

Comment: Alright, I've submitted it to CodePen support. Thanks